# Get element from string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a large string in a variable that includes a whole bunch of HTML tags.

I want to get the value of a hidden input field within the string and store it in its own var.

```
<input type="hidden" value="WantThis" />
```

Can anyone help me out at all?

Comment: can you post complete html tag? You can use Jquery to get the value!

Comment: I'm confused... so you have a var that is a large string with HTML tags, then you have a hidden input, and you want to store it in its own var? Wait.. what?

Comment: Explain more. A simple syntax like this `$('input[type=hidden]').val()` can achieve what you want, that is if I understand you correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the HTML with jQuery to get the value:

```
var theValue = $(myString).find('input[name=something]').val();
```

I'm assuming the hidden field has a name. If it doesn't, you'll need to specify `input[type=hidden]` and find it using its position relative to the rest of the content.

If your string does not already have a root element and the `<input>` is not nested, you'll probably want to use `$('<div>' + myString + '</div>')` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Get the hidden input like so:

```
$(html).find("input[type=hidden]").val()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an ID for the hidden input and call it like normal

`<input type="hidden" value="WantThis" id="myInput" />`

Then call it

`var myval = $('#myInput').val();`